# write a make file to compile all standalone tikz file

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, makefile

I wrote several standalone tex files for drawing a figure with tikz, I named them with the pattern tikz_*.tex, and now I want to compile them all at once using a make file. First I tried the following

```
tikz_%.pdf:  tikz_%.tex                                                                                                                                                                          
             pdflatex tikz_$*.tex
```

Secondly, how can I make a rule to generate all the pdf files in Makefile?
I know I could make another rule and list all the pdfs I want to compile but there are too many such files.

Comment: If you install `latexmk`, it's just `latexmk tikz_*.tex`. It will rebuild only the ones they need to be rebuilt.

Comment: What flavour is your `make` utility? If it's GNU make, I have a solution. For other versions, I don't. (But of course, using `latexmk` as suggested above should work regardless.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, yes latexmk works perfectly, but i also want to know how that works for GNU make?

Comment: BTW, you can produce multiple standalones using the [tikz] or [multi=tikcpicture] options (one per page).  You can select which page to use with the [page=...] option of \includegraphcs.

Comment: I added an answer with GNU make. Another tip: In your implicit rule, you can replace `tikz_$*.tex` by `$<`, meaning the first prerequisite.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it with GNU make:

```
tikz_%.pdf:  tikz_%.tex
    pdflatex $<  # Note: This must be indented with a TAB, not 4 Spaces!

PDFs = $(addsuffix .pdf, $(basename $(wildcard tikz_*.tex)))
all: $(PDFs)
```

Make sure to add your implicit rule at the top of the makefile, and you should be good to go.

The functions are [documented in the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions).

Important caveat: Using this with your implicit rules depends on the tex files needing only one run. If they don't, use `latexmk -pdf` or similar tools instead of `pdflatex`.